# How to remove a video file from the cache in internet explorer

Tags: c#, flash, internet-explorer, iis

In internet explorer, I have the setting "Every time I visit the webpage" option in the Tools->Internet Options->(Browsing History) Settings and this ensures that each time I access a video in a flash player the video is fetched from the server.

However, if I set the setting to "Automatic" the video is not returned from the server and a cached copy is used. I tried using the clientCache settings in Web.config (i.e. useMaxAge/UserExpires/DisableCache) but the video is returned on the first request but there after the cached version is played.

In Fiddler I can see the first request being made for the video and after that only the cached version is played and hence no http request is made.

So with the "Automatic" setting for temporary files, how can I get the video to be returned from the server each time?

**Edit**

Clearly as Eric mentioned this is a caching issue rather than a Flash player or IE issue.

I checked with fiddler and I have headers as:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 76278442
Content-Type: video/mp4
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:47:29 GMT
ETag: "2117329216"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.7
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2013 07:42:23 GMT

and the caching tab in fiddler tells me:

HTTP/200 responses are cacheable by default, unless Expires, Pragma, or Cache-Control headers are present and forbid caching.
HTTP/1.1 ETAG Header is present: "2117329216"
HTTP Last-Modified Header is present: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:47:29 GMT

No Explicit HTTP Expiration information was provided. Most browsers utilize heuristic expiration policies:
10% of the delta between Last-Modified and Date is '02:20:50.5000000' so this response will heuristically expire 22/08/2013 11:52:54.

So I tried every combination from [clientCache](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache) entry in web.config and I cannot seem to add the Cache-Control : no-Cache header so that IE will respect it and not use it's own heuristic algorithm.

Not sure if this has anything to do with it but we create folders under a main virtual folder "Archives" when videos are uploaded.

Folder structures are in the format : Archives/Archive1/0000/01/MP4/High for example where the numbers increase on each upload.

So in web config I have:

```
 <location path="Archives">
   <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
     </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

yet no Cache-control header is added.

I even tried referencing a specific folder:

```
  <location path="Archives/Archive1/0000/22/MP4/High">
    <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
           <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
         </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
```

and still no header is added (although in IIS when I check the directory Archives/Archive1/0000/22/MP4/High I can see the header set when clicking "Set Common Headers" on the "High" folder).

Any ideas?

I noticed in the reponse "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 X-Mod-H264-Streaming", has this got anything to do with the problem of caching?

Comment: The user's question is more properly phrased as: "What does AUTOMATIC mean, and how do I make my content re-download on every use?" The answer can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442(v=vs.85).aspx. You need to set your cache headers appropriately; update your question with the response headers as seen in Fiddler.

Comment: I found that if I go to IIS management console and add response header on "Archives" as a Custom HTTP Response Header (as "Cache-Control" for Name field and "no-cache" for the Value field) then the caching seems to work. Why is this? Why does it not work in Web.Config?